# explanation of tuckey rule "to"

Tags: tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have this rule:

```
<rule>
  <from>^/test/.*$</from>
  <to last="true">-</to>
</rule>
```

Can someone explain what the dash (-) means in the "to" part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means, stop execution/checking of further rules and proceed the request to application